# Is there better way to make list into list of lists C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want have following class, and I want to change my object from `List<CharacterDto>` into `List<Character>` using LINQ, and the output will be in json.

```
public class Character
{
    public int Id
    public string Name
    public List<item> Items
}
public class Item
{
    public string ItemName
    public int ItemId
}
public class CharacterDto
{
    public int Id
    public string Name
    public string ItemName
    public int ItemId
}
```

Example:

```
CharacterDto:
{Id = 1, Name = "Archer", ItemName = "Bow", ItemId = 2},
{Id = 1, Name = "Archer", ItemName = "Armor", ItemId = 1},
{Id = 2, Name = "Warrior", ItemName = "Sword", ItemId = 3},
{Id = 2, Name = "Warrior", ItemName = "Armor", ItemId = 1},
{Id = 3, Name = "Mage", ItemName = "Armor", ItemId = 1}
```

```
Character:
{Id = 1, Name = "Archer", Items:{ItemName = "Armor", ItemId = 1},{ItemName = "Bow", ItemId = 2}},
{Id = 2, Name = "Warrior", Items:{ItemName = "Armor", ItemId = 1},{ItemName = "Sword", ItemId = 3}},
{Id = 3, Name = "Mage", Items:{ItemName = "Armor", ItemId = 1}}
```

I currently have a work around, but it look very messy.

```
public class Character
{
    public int Id
    public string Name
    public List<CharacterDto> Items
}
public class CharacterDto
{
    [JsonIgnore]public int Id
    [JsonIgnore]public string Name
    public string ItemName
    public int ItemId
}
public List<character> function(){
    List<CharacterDto> data = getFromDB();
    List<Character> Characters = data.GroupBy(x => new {x.Id, x.Name}).Select(y => new Character()
    {
        Id = y.Key.Id, 
        Name = y.Key.Name, 
        Items = y.ToList()
    }).ToList();
    return Characters
```

EDIT: the better i mean by i dont want JsonIgnore in the class, and I want to use `List<item>` and not `List<CharacterDto>` in class Charactor

Comment: I don't see what's "messy" about your solution. Please define what is "less messy".

Comment: What is wrong with "workaround" (for me it looks like standard data manipulation for such cases)? Also please define "better".

Comment: looks fine to me - probably rename the metod `function()` to  `GetCharacters()`

Comment: You can project the grouped element in List<Item> using select and To list like you just have  : `Items = y.Select(c=> new Item{ItemName=c.ItemName, ItemId=c.Item}).ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `Character.Items` to be a `List<item>` instead of `List<CharacterDto>`.
First we have to change the object definition:

```
public class Character
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Item> Items {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can use Select to map the grouped `CharacterDto` to `Item`:

```
Items = y.Select(c=> new Item{ ItemName = c.ItemName, ItemId = c.Item }).ToList()
```